# Count frequency of characters in a file

Tags: haskell, io

Some patterns are emerging ("fmap (b->a) . fmap (c->b) . .. . (IO z)"). Also infix `zip` is kind-of a hack.

What is:

1. Best practice in point-free style?
2. Best practice?

Elegance > Performance;  Functional > Imperative

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

fromFile :: FilePath -> IO (M.Map Char Int)
fromFile = fmap (M.fromListWith (+)) . fmap (`zip` [1,1..]) . readFile
    where readFile = fmap BS.unpack . BS.readFile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice would be to separate the pure operations of your program from those that actually require IO. Counting the frequency of elements in a list doesn't require any IO, so you should tease that `fromFile` function apart into its constituent components for reusability, testing, comprehensibility, or whatever other purpose you'd like.

```
frequencies :: Ord k => [k] -> Map k Int
frequencies = fromListWith (+) . (`zip` [1,1..])

fromFile :: FilePath -> IO (Map Char Int)
fromFile = fmap frequencies . fmap unpack . readFile
```

I'd tweak this just a bit further, using `repeat` from the Prelude to build the infinite list instead of abusing list ranges, and to take advantage of the Functor laws and drop a few characters. I flip back and forth on writing functions in pointfree style when it requires infix sectioning too, in this case I'd probably keep the points but I don't know that one choice is clearly better than the other.

```
frequencies ks = fromListWith (+) $ zip ks (repeat 1)

fromFile = fmap (frequencies . unpack) . readFile
```

Comment: Need 2 reps to Up you:). I agree on IO separation and `repeat`.

Comment: @xged you got it!